# how to verify if a checkbox is checked in jQuery before submission

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
<select name="status" id='status'>
    <option value="Submitted">Submitted</option>
    <option value="Canceled">Canceled</option>

</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="app_box" name="application_complete" value="checked"> App Complete

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $('form.editable').submit(function(){ 
        if ($('#status').val()=='Canceled') { 
            if (!confirm('This  information will be discarded! )) { 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    }); 

}); 
</script>
```

So, I have the above script which works fine. I have to add one more confirmation. When the agent clicks on the submit button , I want to check if the application check box is checked or not. If it is not checked then display another confirmation box saying, you have to check the box. How can this be done in jquery.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
if ($('#app_box').is(':checked')){...}
```

Or

```
if ($('#app_box')[0].checked){...}
```

So here is how your code should be:

```
$('form.editable').submit(function(){ 
    if (! $('#app_box')[0].checked){
       alert('Check App Complete first !');
       return false;
    }

    if ($('#status').val() == 'Canceled') { 
        if (!confirm('This  information will be discarded!' )) { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
});
```

---

Learn more:

- http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: ok I have silly question which I did not find in the docs. how do i check if the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: @user856753: By putting `!` before condition like I have done above in `if (! $('#app_box')[0].checked){` or using `false` like `if ( $('#app_box')[0].checked === false){`. Both will do it.

Answer (score 1):

[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

(Documentation is your best friend...)

Comment: also, a simple search on google as 'jquery checkbox checked' gives lot of results. The first one being http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='application_complete']").is(":checked"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $('form.editable').submit(function(){ 
        if ($('#status').val()=='Canceled') { 

            //check if the box is checked!
            if ($("#app_box").is(':checked')) {
               alert("You have to check the box 'App Complete'"); 
               return false;
            }

            if (!confirm('This  information will be discarded! )) { 
                return false;
            } 
        } 
    }); 

}); 
</script>
```

I hope it helps!